# Normalise X/Y coordinates to stop jitter

Tags: data-visualization, svm, normalization

*Disclaimer: I am a programmer by trade, not a statistician, so please cater to my ignorance and I apologize now if I make any incorrect assumptions*

Please consider the following problem:

I am using machine learning to predict an x/y coordinate of a point, on an frame, in a video with fairly accurate results. Each time a new frame is loaded from the video, I am re-predicting the position. Often the position has not moved very far (if at all) between the two frames, however due to the algorithm not predicting perfectly there is a small amount (sometimes quite large jumps aswell) of *jitter* when overlaying the points on the video.

Now I had considered comparing the points x/y with the x/y of the previous frame, and calculating the absolute distance between them, and then if this is over a certain threshold, do not move the point, or perhaps move the point part of the way towards the next x/y, however this may cause issues with genuine quick movements, as well as I cannot think of an intelligent way to choose what the threshold would be.

I hope I have explained myself well enough, and I am open to any advise you may have, if you refer to a known statistical algorithm or method, please either explain it in plain english, or link me to somewhere where I can read about it.

Comment: Hello @Aphire, what is now your concrete question?

Comment: Hello @Qaswed, My question is: what can I apply to my data to reduce the jitter I am experiencing

Comment: Could you tell us more information about the movements? I'm thinking you should consider more than one frame when assesing distance between points, taking in consideration that jitter errors should cancell each other in  many frames and other movements should not.

Comment: Hi @camilaaab, I have taken that on board, and I am now computing 3 frames and trying to identify any large changes in the second frame, that don't appear in the first and third, this is working quite well, but there is still a fair bit of small jitter, what else would you like to know about the points?

Comment: If movements were only in one direction for several frames, you could use moving averages to first classify jitter from non jitter and then smooth the jittered ones.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple approach would be to smooth the output of your first model. A [Savitzky-Golay filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Savitzky%E2%80%93Golay_filter) might work, which tries to approximate the signal using a local polynomial model. As a plus, this type of filter can also compute derivatives of a noisy signal, so it could also be used to calculate velocity (if you're interested in that).

Another approach would be to use a [Kalman filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter), which is commonly used for position tracking with noisy signals. This treats the signal (the output of your first model) as a noisy observation of some underlying dynamical state (the position). It tries to estimate the underlying state from the data. If you want to take a similar approach in the discrete domain (i.e. pixel coordinates), you could use a [hidden Markov model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_markov_model).

A different type of strategy would be to modify your machine learning algorithm that estimates the coordinates. For example, you could imagine applying some form of regularization that encourages it to produce smooth outputs.

Comment: Thank you very much for the info. I will look into this.